# Integer arguments being interpreted as String arguments in Java

Tags: java

Code:

```
class Foo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        int x[] = new int[5];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            x[i]=i*i;

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Value #" + i+1 + " = " + x[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The Output:

```
tk@insomniac-tk:~$ java Foo
Value #01 = 0
Value #11 = 1
Value #21 = 4
Value #31 = 9
Value #41 = 16
```

So, what's going on here? Where am I messing up my java code? I mean why is it that in Java, the `i+1` means literally `i` concat `1`?

Comment: The concatenation is done from left to right. So `"Value #" + i` is executed at first and Sting+Integer is interpreted as String concatenation. Use Parentheses to indicate that you want to execute i+1 before the concatenation.

Comment: You are doing two different things. In Java you print a concatenated string, and in C++ you print separate "items".

Comment: To fix it: `System.out.println("Value #" + (i+1) + " = " + x[i]);`

Comment: `+` has a higher operator precedence in C++ than `<<`.

Comment: This question has been asked many times. This is a duplicate of duplicated questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Foo 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
    int x[] = new int[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        x[i]=i*i;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Value # " + (i+1) + " = " + x[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

try this

Comment: Yes! It worked! Correct me if I'm wrong , every System.out.println() takes strings as args and unless specified explicity will not use integers?

Comment: @insomniac_tk the println method will has multiple overloaded methods, including one for ints. However, because there are Strings, the println method that accepts a String parameter is used

Comment: @JohnD Yep that makes sense . thanks m8!

Answer (score 4):

In `Strings` the `+` operator is used for concatenate, so because you did not specidy any parenthesis, your `i` and `1` are also concatentate, you need to use parenthesis to explicitly tell that they to be sum together :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("Value #" + (i + 1) + " = " + x[i]);
}
```

To get :

```
Value #1 = 0
Value #2 = 1
Value #3 = 4
Value #4 = 9
Value #5 = 16
```

---

Next to that, another way using `IntStream`, which will do same :

```
IntStream.range(0, 5)
         .mapToObj(i -> "Value #" + (i + 1) + " = " + (i * i))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

The + means something like concat, if you want the expression to be evaluated put it into brackets

> (i + 1) not i + 1

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
System.out.println("Value #" + i+1 + " = " + x[i]);
```

And in particular

```
"Value #" + i+1 + " = " + x[i]
```

Is syntactic sugar for the following code:

```
new StringBuffer().append("Value #")
                  .append(i)
                  .append(1)
                  .append(" = ")
                  .append(x[i])
                  .toString();
```

What you want is this:

```
"Value #" + (i+1) + " = " + x[i]
```

Which would translate to

```
new StringBuffer().append("Value #")
                  .append(i+1)
                  .append(" = ")
                  .append(x[i])
                  .toString();
```

Comment: Java newbie here. So didn't get most of that , but still I did try the parenthesis on i+1 and that works!

Answer (score 2):

Because in this case, Java append `i` to your String, then 1 to your String.

To evaluate the value first (and produce the result you are expecting here), you have to inform Java that you want to evaluate the value before it is appended, using parenthesis:

```
System.out.println("Value #" + (i+1) + " = " + x[i]);
```

**Output**

```
Value #1 = 0
Value #2 = 1
Value #3 = 4
Value #4 = 9
Value #5 = 16
```

Answer (score 2):

The key reason the Java and C++ programs differ is because the operators used are different:

```
System.out.println("Value #" + i+1 + " = " + x[i]); // Java
cout << "Value # " << i + 1 << " =  " << x[i] << endl; // C++
```

The `+` operator has a [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and hence the addition is done before the overloaded `<<` operator.

In the Java version it is all `+`s and so they are all evaluated left to right.

Comment: Whoa this is cool. Thanks m8!

Answer (score 0):

problem is in system.out.println("");,where all integers will concatinate into string when added using(+) with a string variable .Try different code for different operations with integer and string variables.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot simply add an integer into a string. You must convert an integer to a string with Integer.toString(int),then add the returned value to the string.

Comment: That's plain wrong, the string concatenation will automatically convert the integer to a string - read the [section in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)